# Symfony 6 API CORS issue

Tags: rest, symfony, http, cors

I'am buildind REST using symfony 6 and Vue. I have issue with CORS. I'm using NelmioCoresBundle.All routes work except PUT and PATCH. When i try to send HTTP PUT request with axios I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/listing' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

This is my configuration in nelmio_cors.yaml:

```
nelmio_cors:
  paths:
    '^/api/':
      allow_headers: ['*']
      allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
      max_age: 3600
```

When i use also `allow_origin: ['*']` like this:

```
nelmio_cors:
  paths:
    '^/api/':
      allow_origin: ['*']
      allow_headers: ['*']
      allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS']
      max_age: 3600
```

then none of the route work and I get this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/category' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:5173, *', but only one is allowed.
```

.I also use JWT bundle fot authentication.
What could be wrong? Is it the configuration of one of the bundles or something else?

Thos is my code to send HTTP request using axios:

```
async editListing(context,payload) {
        try {
            const formData = payload.formData
            const token = context.rootGetters.getToken
            const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/listing',formData,{
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })

            if(response.status!==200){
                throw new Error(response.data.message || 'Failed to edit listing')
            }

            console.log(response)

            return response.data
        }catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Maybe it's about my docker nginx configuration:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;
```

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was  about nginx configuration. all I had to do was add these lines to the configuration file in the location section:

```
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' always;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;
        }
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
```